# How get share count on "Viadeo" link

Tags: php, json, share, viadeo

I want get the share count on my Viadeo link like I can do with other social API with a json file.

I have tried to do that: https://api.viadeo.com/recommend?url=http://myURL.dev but it's doesnt work. It give me some informations but not the share count.

Someone have an idea for help me to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it won't work on a dummy url. You should provide a valid one first. It seems it return a JSON. Just use a simple `json_decode()`. Example:

```
$url = 'https://api.viadeo.com/recommend?url=http://us.viadeo.com/en/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$results = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($results, true);
echo $data['count']; // for this example it should show 
// 12
```

Comment: Of course I shouldnt do that on a dummy url. I know. It's just for the example. But with a normal it won't work too ;)

Comment: It's ok. I found my problem. I have ask the wrong item. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Metra oh okay, maybe you should add also how you got it working, SO is a library too, maybe other might find it useful in the future

Answer (score 0):

I have used the wrong item. It's work now.

Comment: Could you post the code you got wrong and then what you changed to fix it so future readers can see what you did?

Comment: The code of Ghost is right. It was a simple stupid problem by my fault ;). I have used the wrong key "share_count" but the right one is "count"